# Extracting information from JSON arrays (Presto SQL)

Tags: sql, json, presto

I'm using Presto 0.282 and I'm wanting to extract information from a JSON array that looks like this

```
['{month_01=0','date_last_activity=2023-01-01','month_02=0','month_03=0','month_04=0','month_05=0}']
```

as json_column

I tried using json_extract and json_extract_scalar but unfamiliar with the way it should be done. I looked at Presto documentation to no avail. Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: This is not JSON. JSON has double quotes. Also `{month_01=0` and `month_05=0}` sounds like issue with inserting data

Comment: If it's not JSON, would it be considered an array?

Comment: Well, `[]` indicates array. But its values are messed up for some reason, so you would have to process it first (just merging values into string would lead to invalid JSON again, need proper processing). Maybe better check why invalid JSON is written to database?

Comment: Okay cool, I'll double check the pre-processing. Thanks!